# What is the way the program works?

Tags: java, variables, methods

```
class MultiFor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {

            for (int y = 4; y > 2; y--) {

                System.out.println(x + " " + y);
            }
            if (x == 1) {
                x++;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

The output according to my book (and in Eclipse) is:

0 4 
0 3 
1 4 
1 3 
3 4 
3 3

Can someone please explain how that works? In my brain the second 0 should be 1 already?!

Comment: The inner loop will run twice. First for `y = 4` and then `y = 3`. Hence `x = 0` being printed twice.

Comment: Why? In the y loop, the value of x does not change

Comment: why does after twice the inner loop then suddenly x increase? does it jump back up to the for int x and adds one to x? because the if x==1 is not relevant yet?

Comment: Best solution: Step through the code with a debugger and *see* what it is doing and why.

Comment: @MarcSpanjol `x==1` is very relevant. It causes the `x++;` to be skipped when `x = 0`.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take step by step.

1. when program enter in first loop it set
   x=0;
2. Now on second loop it set value  of y
   y = 4
3. Upper limit of y is set as y < 2 which means this loop will run for y = 4 and y = 3. you are not changing value of x inside second loop.
   so the output is
   0 4
   0 3
   **So for the value of x =0 second loop will run twice**

Let's take further
4.  After this programe will check value of x which is still 0 so if will set as false
5. Now based on increment operator on first loop, programe will increase value of x by 1 and than set y value of y =4 again.
6 This will execute second loop again twice.
and generate output as
1 4
1 3

7. Now it will reach your if statement again and now value of x is 1. this will increase value of x by 1 set it as x =2
8. Programe will reach on first loop increment statment and increase value of x on more time. Now value if x will be 3
9. Second loop will again twice for Value of x =3
   3 4
   3 3